# How to remove insertion process in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to mysql and php and i am self taught so there is no one to put me through. How can i remove this insertion process in my php file whenever i insert, because it is inserting well but i want to remove the process. 
My PHP code is below

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['insert_quiz'])) {
     var_dump($_POST);
     $quiz_add_id = $_SESSION['quiz_id'];
     $count = $_SESSION['quiz_no'];
     if (
       !empty($_POST['question']) && !empty($_POST['optionA']) && !empty($_POST['optionB']) && !empty($_POST['optionC']) && !empty($_POST['optionD']) && count($_POST['op1']) === count($_POST['question'])) 
     {
        $question_array = $_POST['question'];
        $optionA_array = $_POST['optionA'];
        $optionB_array = $_POST['optionB'];
        $optionC_array = $_POST['optionC'];
        $optionD_array = $_POST['optionD'];
        $op1_array = $_POST['op1'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $question = $question_array[$i];
            $op1 = $op1_array[$i];
            $optionA = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $optionA_array[$i]);
            $optionB = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $optionB_array[$i]);
            $optionC = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $optionC_array[$i]);
            $optionD = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $optionD_array[$i]);

            $query = "INSERT INTO quizzes (quiz_add_id, quiz_question, quiz_option_A, quiz_option_B, quiz_option_C, quiz_option_D, quiz_option_correct)";

            $query .= "VALUES ('{$quiz_add_id}', '{$question}', '{$optionA}','{$optionB}','{$optionC}','{$optionD}', '{$op1}')";

            $create_quiz_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        } 
        if(!$create_quiz_query ) {
              die('QUERY FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
//     
     }
 }
?>
```

THis is what i dont want to see anymore when i insert

[image]

Comment: Get rid of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Thanks. I dont even know the need of it, someone here yesterday said i should put it in my code but didnt tell me why. Thanks @JohnConde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove below code

```
var_dump($_POST);
```